# C - calling a function via func_ptr, why doesnt it work?

Tags: c, function, pointers

i have the following code:

```
void print(const char* str){
      system_call(4,1,str,strlen(str)); }

void foo2(void){ print("goo \n");}


void buz(void){ ...}

int main(){
char buf[256];
    void (*func_ptr)(void)=(void(*)(void))buf;
    memcpy(buf,foo2, ((void*)buz)-((void*)foo2));
    func_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

the question is, why will this code fall?

the answer was, something about calling a function not via pointer is to a relative address, but i havent been able to figure out whats wrong here? which line is the problematic one?

thank you for your help

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior and is legally allowed to do anything? Among other things, you'll probably need to make the data in `buf` executable. Operating systems have protections to prevent people from doing things like this.

Comment: You seem to have left out a `}` on `print`.

Comment: Hmya, explore viral code by the looks of it.  You fell victim to a basic one, relative addressing.  The absolute addressing loophole has been plugged too, it is called 'address space layout randomization'.  And the NX bit added to cores as of late.

Answer (score 3):

Well to begin with, there is nothing which says that foo2() and buz() must be next to each other in memory. And for another, as you guess, the code must be relative for stunts like that to work. But most of all, it is not allowed by the standard.

As Chris Luts referred to, stack (auto) variables are not executable on many operating systems, to protect from attacks.

Comment: And you can't really just move executable bytes, without properly relocating any necessary symbols.

Comment: I didn't even think about that. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The first two lines in your main() function are problematic.

Line 1.  `(void(*)(void))buf`
converting buf to a function pointer is undefined

Line 2.  `((void*)buz)-((void*)foo2)`
subtraction of pointers is undefined unless the pointers point within the same array.

Also, `Section 5.8 Functions` of `H&S` says "Although a pointer to a function is often assumed to be the address of the function's code in memory, on some computers a function pointer actually points to a block of information needed to invoke the function."

Comment: Also in line 2, casting function pointers to non-function pointer types is illegal.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I believe casting function pointers to (void*) is allowed.  The only defined operation on the resulting void pointer would be to cast it back to the original function pointer type.

Comment: @sigjuice - You'd be wrong. You can cast them to a generic function pointer type (I use `typedef void (*func)(void);` myself) and back freely, but the C standard does not allow casting them to `void *`. (I believe POSIX _does_ allow casting them to `void` however.)

Comment: @Chris Lutz: "5.3.3 Some Caution With Pointers" of H&S says "In Standard C, void * can be used as a generic object pointer, but there is no generic function pointer."

Comment: Check the standard itself. I would cite it but I'm on an iPhone.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I stand corrected.  6.3.2.3§8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, C function pointers mechanism is for equal-signature function calling abstraction. This is powerful and error-prone enough without these stunts.

I can't see an advantage/sense in trying to copying code from one place to another. As some have commented, it's not easy to tell the amount of relativeness/rellocatable code within a C function.

You tried copying the code of a function onto a data memory region. Some microcontrollers would just told you "Buzz off!". On machine architectures that have data/program separated memories, given a very understanding compiler (or one that recognizes data/code modifiers/attributes), it would compile to the specific Code-Data Move instructions. It seams it would work... However, even in data/code separated memory archs, data-memory instruction execution is not possible.

On the other hand, in "normal" data/code shared memory PCs, likely it would also not work because data/code segments are declared (by the loader) on the MMU of the processor. Depending on the processor and OS, attempts to run code on data segments, is a segmentation fault.

Comment: first of all, thank you all for your replies. from what i understand, the idea itself is not possible, and moreover, the copy of compiled code into data segment and the running of code from that segment will cause segmentation fault. the relative call idea is minor, but still of importance for such "stunts" to work. and again, your info was priceless.

Comment: R.A. not impossible, but you would have to be very lucky to find the combination of compiler and OS which results in that code working. If you want to copy code around, it's easier to go for assembler directly.